# How can I source a bash script inside of a bash select case

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to find a way to source a options file into my case script as shown below:
main file

```
case "$1" in                                                                 
. options                                                                      
esac
```

options file

```
#options file               
1 ) do something
2 ) do something else
```

Has anyone got any ideas as all I am getting is a 'parse error' 
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can you post your full code with the error you got.

Comment: You mean you want to substitute in **the options themselves**? You can't do that. Not supported.

Comment: if you wanted to do `case "$1" in foo) . options;; esac`, then *that* would work perfectly fine.

Comment: BTW, is this really bash (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/bin/bash`, etc) or POSIX sh (`#!/bin/sh`) you're asking about? Most folks writing bash would use `source` instead of `.` -- if you're needing to be POSIX-compliant, then that means some other parts of my answer would need to change (ie. using the less-efficient `$(cat foo)` instead of `$(<foo)`).

Comment: BTW -- I do second Inian here -- even though I know the actual error you're getting, a good question includes its literal text, not just describing it as "a 'parse error'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, what you *really* want to do is to be able to add handlers for different values of `$1` from external source files -- potentially an arbitrary number of such files, without them being aware of each other.

That's a perfectly fine thing to want. Don't use `case` to do it.

Consider the following:

```
# base-options
do__1() { echo "doing something"; }
do__2() { echo "doing something else; }
```

...and, perhaps, a separate file:

```
# extra-options
do__foo() { echo "doing yet another thing"; }
```

Now, from your main file, you can just source all these in:

```
# this loop will source in both base-options and extra-options
for f in *options; do
  source "$f"
done

# and here, if we *have* a command -- either as a shell function or an external command --
# corresponding to our $1, we run that command.
if type "do__$1" >/dev/null; then
  cmd="do__$1"; shift
  "$cmd" "$@"
else
  echo "Handler for $1 not found" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

Going the approach above also means that your handlers *don't need to be shell functions at all*! If you have an executable file named `do__1`, it'll be found by `type` so long as it's in your PATH, so you can write handlers in any language you want -- you're not locking yourself into bash.

This is closely related to how `git` handles subcommands -- see all the `git-foo` executables handling `git foo` commands. It's a common practice, and a good one. Use it.

Comment: Thank you for all you help this is just what I was looking for sorry about the wording

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

The following works fine:

```
# options
case "$1" in
  1) something ;;
  2) something else ;;
esac
```

and, in your original code:

```
. options "$@"
```

...and all that differs from what you were trying to do is that you're adding a header and footer to `options`.

---

#### Explanation

`.` (or `source`) is itself a command. If you can't put arbitrary commands in a position, then you can't put a source command there either.

Since your options file is necessarily written *knowing* that it'll go inside a `case` statement, why not just put the `case` and `esac` lines inside it? This doesn't make it any less flexible: `$1` can be overridden in the `source` command itself:

```
. my.sh "$@" # this passes the current arguments through...
```

whereas:

```
# this still works without changing options
. my.sh "$foo" # this passes $foo as $1
```

---

#### Alternate Ugly Literal Broken Hack

As a very ugly, awful hack that'll break a bunch of debugging functionality, you could do something like:

```
# Don't do this; it'll cause headaches later.
eval 'case "$1" in '"$(<options)"'; esac'
```

Comment: This way works I can see its untidy but I does mean I can separate the options and in turn add to them later thanks

Comment: Which is "this way"? If you mean the hack, as I said, it'll break a bunch of debugging functionality. If you want to use `set -x` to trace your program's execution, `LINENO` and `BASH_SOURCE` won't accurately know where the sources being executed come from.

Comment: Frankly, if what you want is to build a big table and match against it, you'd be better off doing that at runtime from your script itself, not trying to use `case` for the purpose at all.

Comment: Another thing that works well, which I've done in the past, is having a convention for function naming -- so you have different files you source in define functions like `do_1` and `do_2` (if your `case`s are 1 and 2), then you look at whether a function named `do_$1` exists and call it if so.

Comment: @Chris: ...so, I reiterate: **There are better ways to accomplish any reasonable real-world goal here**, and if you asked us how best to achieve that goal, you'd probably get an answer that didn't include `case` at all.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice i'm quite new to this, which way would you say would be the overall best way in achieving the result I only used case as it was one of the ways in which i could achieve the result, thanks again

Comment: See the separate answer I've added. It's making a bunch of guesses about your real intent, because the question isn't explicit, but hopefully they're accurate ones.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to match against `$1` first, otherwise what is the point of the `case` statement?

```
case "$1" in
 options) . options ;;
 things)  echo "What should I do with things?" ;;
 *) echo "I don't know what you want" ;;
esac
```

---

Upon seeing the update, the correct thing to do is to wrap the *entire* case statement in a function defined in your external file.

```
handle_options () {
    case "$1" in 
        1 ) do something ;;
        2 ) do something else ;;
    esac
}
```

Then call that function from the script that sources your file.

```
. somefile
handle_options "$1"
```

Comment: I read the OP as saying they want to put the *options* -- the things to match against -- in the file.

Comment: Ah, yes. Ugh, ick. The OP wants to be programming in TeX, apparently.

Comment: I am trying to keep the options separate so that i can continue to add to them later and build up the case statement on the fly

Comment: @chepner, ...so, through appropriate use of ESP, I think I've figured out the OP's real intent. What's your take (as the other person with an answer in-place) on whether the question should be edited to better reflect same?